# How to grant "select" on more than one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

i want to do something like

```
grant select on arpg.t_account,arpg.t_char to peeker@'localhost';
```

but fails, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you can write a script to manage it for you. There is also some functionality in the MySQL admin tools to let you do it with point and click ease.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Not in a single statement. You can't even use a wildcard such as arpg.t_% here.